# Can I hide actual download link?

Tags: laravel

Is there any method available in Laravel which I can use my URL to download, while hiding the actual download URL of another website I'm using?

I read many methods for hiding the own url but unable to find a way to hide an external URL. I want to hide this external site download URL:   [click here](https://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/themes/APKMirror/download.php?id=707634)

Route

```
Route::post('/registration',['uses'=>'AppController@getregistration','as'=>'registration']);
```

**View**

```
{!!Form::open(array('url' => '/registration')) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('course_id', '1') !!}
    {!! Form::submit('registration') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Controller**

```
public function getregistration(Request $request)
{   
    $course_id = $request->input('course_id');
    return view('index')->with('course_id',$course_id);
}
```

Get method
use encryption method, it will show encrypted id in url

**View**

```
<li>
    <a  href="{{route('registration',['course_id' => Crypt::encrypt('1') ])}}">A</a>
</li>
```

**Controller**

```
public function getregistration($course_id)
{    
    $course_id = Crypt::decrypt($course_id);    
    return view('index')->with('course_id',$course_id);
}
```

Comment: Send a request to your server, make it download the content using the URL you don't want to reveal and return the content to your user.

Comment: @marekful Any example will greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: You control serverA, the content is on serverB. You don't want to reveal urlB that points to the content on the third party serverB. So you render urlA on your website which points to your serverA. When the user clicks urlA, the request is processed by your serverA. ServerA knows urlB and it makes a request to the content on serverB and returns it in response to urlA being requested by your user. The point is that the download of the content from serverB does not occur directly to the browser of your user so there's no need for the user to know urlB. The download happens on you serverA.

Comment: @marekful plz give me example so that I can understand easily Bro I am new in laravel.

Comment: You have to be able to understand the concept by this description. I cannot give you example as I don't know Laravel.

Comment: @NishantItz: You may be misunderstanding what this community does, and you are encouraged to start here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour  It's unlikely that anybody here will provide you with a complete working solution which you can copy/paste into your own application.  As a result of that request, this question is essentially too broad to be meaningfully answered here.  Instead, you are encouraged to make an attempt.  The comments above describe the overall process to be broken down into individual components.  If you encounter a specific error on any piece, we can help with that.

Comment: Besides, stop keep insisting that you are presented with a working solution. Use your brains bro.

Comment: OK thnx Bro don't be angry

Comment: @NishantItz: For the overall functionality that's been described, you essentially need to (1) make an HTTP request from PHP code and either (2a) download the response into a file (and subsequently respond to the user with that file) or (2b) stream the response to the user.  Which of the latter two may depend heavily on the framework(s) you're using.

Comment: No worries, and I didn't downvote...

Comment: @David (2a) downloading resource into the file will consume time and ram also I will like to go with option 1 and thnx a lot :-)

Comment: I find the answer :-)

Comment: <?php
$file = "http://example.com/go.exe"; 

header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($file)); 

readfile ($file);
exit();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by @marekful , you can server-side download the file and then prompt download based on the newly created file's URL.

Using Laravel's GuzzleHttp:

```
$local_file = fopen('./local_file.txt', 'w');
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$client->get('https://external-site.com/file.txt', ['sink' => $local_file]);
```